# What is "Attack Pattern Shinzon Theta"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-nemesis

In *Star Trek: Nemesis*, Shinzon issues the command "Attack Pattern Shinzon Theta" during a volley of attacks against Picard in the Enterprise.

What exactly are the goals of the pattern and how was it executed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It appears that this command is shorthand for "*fly straight over the enemy vessel and shoot at them when you get close, while remaining cloaked*".

[image]

> Shinzon was gloating. "You're too slow, old man." He began punching
> commands directly into the control panel of his chair console. "Attack
> pattern Shinzon Theta."
>
> He watched, a small, malevolent smile on his lips **as the invisible
> Scimitar ran straight over the Enterprise, firing down on her at close
> range.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Nemesis: Official Novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis_(novel))</sup></sub>

This tallies nicely with what we see on screen and what's in the screenplay.

> **INT.  SCIMITAR - BRIDGE**
> SHINZON: You're too slow, old man.(entering commands in his chair console) Attack pattern Shinzon Theta.
>
> **EXT.  THE RIFT - SPACE**
> **The invisible Warbird makes a dramatic run straight over the Enterprise -- firing steadily down as it sweeps past it**; is a brutal, close range assault --
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: Nemesis - Screenplay](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek-Nemesis.html)</sup></sub>